# C# Save File Dialogue.Show() Throwing Error

Tags: c#, webforms, savefiledialog

I was creating a youtube video extractor. Everything was working fine. But i wanted to add a save file dialogue to ask for save location. It is showing error - System.Threading.ThreadStateException
HResult=0x80131520
Message=Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.
Source=
StackTrace:

[Error Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9GOR.png)

My Code

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
 saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
 saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Your File";
 var youTube = YouTube.Default; // starting point for YouTube actions
 var video = youTube.GetVideo(link); // gets a Video object with info about the video
 saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
 string location = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
 File.WriteAllBytes( location + video.FullName, video.GetBytes());
```

I am buliding it in C# WebForms

Please Help Me I am new to programming

Comment: Where is that code exactly? The error message makes it sound like it's being executed on a secondary thread. You need to make sure that you use UI elements like dialogues on the UI thread only.

Comment: If you have resolved your own issue, please post an answer and accept it. I think everyone can do that. Questions should not be left unanswered as that defeats the purpose of the site, which is to created a catalogue of questions and answers that everyone can use.